# Multiplying within a nested dictionary or using Matrices?

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, matrix, linear-algebra

EDIT: THE OBJECTIVE: to do something for a nested dictionary with n number of the nested keys (i.e. the A,B,C,D) to get a number in Cell A10. See image below of excel depiction of the problem.

[image: objective]

I have done the following piece of code to multiply matched keys in my nested dictionary.

I was wondering:

1. How to make this a lot cleaner and
2. If there is a better, in terms of processing time, way to set up this nested dictionary to get the desired results.

See below my attempted code for the problem at hand.

```
objs = {1: {'A': [-1]},
        2: {'B': [2], 'A': [2]},
        3: {'B': [15], 'C': [-3], 'A': [18]}
        }

c = Counter()
c1 = Counter()
c2 = Counter()
dic = {}
dic1 = {}
dic2 = {}

for k, v in objs.iteritems():
   for k1, v1 in v.iteritems():
       if k != 3:
          c[k1] += 1
          val = dic.setdefault(k1, [0])
          if val[0] == 0:
              dic[k1] = map(add, val, v1)
           else:
                dic[k1] = map(mul, val, v1)
       if k != 1:
           c1[k1] += 1
           val = dic1.setdefault(k1, [0])
           if val[0] == 0:
               dic1[k1] = map(add, val, v1)
           else:
               dic1[k1] = map(mul, val, v1)
       if k != 2:
           c2[k1] += 1
           val = dic2.setdefault(k1, [0])
           if val[0] == 0:
               dic2[k1] = map(add, val, v1)
           else:
               dic2[k1] = map(mul, val, v1)
print dic, dic1, dic2
print c, c1, c2
for k, v in c.iteritems():
   if v > 1:
     a = int(dic[k][0]) * 0.4
     print a
for k, v in c1.iteritems():
    if v > 1:
        b = int(dic1[k][0]) * 0.4
        print b
for k, v in c2.iteritems():
    if v > 1:
        c = int(dic2[k][0]) * 0.2
        print c
```

Then essentially I have a formula that will sum up all the `a`, `b` and `c`'s. But I can see speed being an issue when considering scale. So I'm thinking of maybe using matrices (via numpy), does anyone have any ideas?.

Comment: Multiply keys matching WHAT by WHAT? Give a concrete example, not just your uncommented code.

Comment: Please fix you indentation.

Comment: @timgeb I've provided an edit

Answer (score 1):

What you definitely should use is to use the key lookup that should definitely be better than `O(n)` in a dictionary.

What you're basically doing is iterating over all keys in the outer dictionary and then all keys on the inner and first then you check if the key in the outer is one of three and runs some code if that's the case. This is inefficient of two reasons, first you iterate through the inner dictionary even if the key of the outer will result in no code being executed, but also that you will have to iterate through the outer dictionary whych is `O(n)`.

Instead you should do key lookups in the outer dictionary and only for these three keys run the inner loop. Something like:

```
def itersel(d, *keys):
    for k in keys:
        try:
            yield k, d[k]
        except KeyError:
            pass


for k, v in itersel(objs, 3, 1, 2):    
    for k1, v1 in v.iteritems():
       if k != 3:
          ...
       if k != 1:
          ...
       if k != 2:
          ...
```

Comment: Thanks for that, it cleans up the code. I've provided a more detailed description of what I'm trying to do. I'd be interested to hear if you have any more thoughts.